# Sharing Session between 2 ASP.NET Requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I am trying to figure out an issue im having:
I have multiple calls to the same function simultaneously.

```
    private const string aaaa= "aaaaa";
    protected bool test()
    {

        if (Session[aaaa] != null && (bool)Session[aaaa])
            return false;

            Session[aaaa] = true;
            return true;
    }
```

Thing is - all my requests ignoring the `Session[aaaa] != null && (bool)Session[aaaa]` and keep on as if no such session variable was defined!

How can It be?
When is the session being updated?

Comment: Where are you adding the `aaaa` session variable, apart from the above code?

Comment: Thats it. Just there. Hey again Oded ;)

Comment: Or you can add a static member into your class. This member will be available on your entire application

Answer (score 1):

you need to set the session variable before you can use it....

```
session.add("aaaa", "some string");
```

then later you can come back and say...

```
string result = session["aaaa"].tostring();
```

Hopefuly this will help

```
    Protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session.Add("BoolTest", "False");
    }

    Protected Bool test()
    {
          return (bool)Session["BoolTest"].tostring();
    }
```

Result; test = false

some point later in the page you would say...

```
Session["BoolTest"] = True;
```

Result; test = true

Comment: This is like doing Session[aaaa] = true, isnt it?

Comment: well... if "aaaa" already exists in session... if not it will simply return a null.  session.add("aaaa", "some string") is used to add that initial session variable to memory.